# What is the best way to display hierarchical options?

Tags: controls, checkboxes

I am working on an UI that allows user to print name tag for visiting guests, some of the guests have VIP status and some don't. The "Primary Guest" is always a VIP and is included by default. Options on this UI are:

1. Primary Guest (Default & Mandatory)
2. Primary Guest + other VIPs
3. All Guests (Primary, VIPs, non-VIPs)

Non-VIPs only is not an option.

Currently this is what I have:

[image: This is what I have for now]

What I'm struggling is I don't think this approach shows the "inclusive" status of the options, they do not weight equally with each other.

Any feedback or suggestion is appreciated, hope I have explained my question well.

Comment: What is the weighting? ie. what is the chance of each of the 3 options?

Comment: @Aadaam Primary Guest only would be the most common scenario, chance of VIPs and All Guests are the same, but they are not edge cases

Answer (score 1):

So far, a simple radio button could suffice:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgW9gJ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If we would know more about the problem, that could help.

**Edit**: Based on your comment above, perhaps a "[Split dropdown button](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split)" like solution would suffice...

[image: Drop button mockup]

It might get confused with a combobox, should be usability tested (depends on the environment and patterns of the actual UI)

Another option could be a "..." button right next to the primary one:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgz9cO.png)</sup>